# Programmatically generating top n queries for Microsoft SQL Server from a general query

Tags: sql-server

I have a program that generates some standard SQL like `SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X`
and passes it (as a string) to a function along with an integer to create a limited query (also a string).  For Oracle (which the application was developed against), this function returns `SELECT * FROM (`sq`) WHERE ROWNUM <=`n giving:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

which works.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to write the equivalent function for Microsoft SQL Server (I'm no MS SQL expert).

I tried:

```
SELECT TOP 10 FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X)
```

but that leads to:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

Then I tried:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X)
```

which gained me:

```
Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

which was frustrating since I am specifying TOP....

I tried a few other shotgun variations including:

```
SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X)
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X) SUBQUERY
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X) AS SUBQUERY
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X) WHERE ROW_NUMBER <= 10
```

but of course, none of them work either.

Is there no hope at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SET ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx). This makes the job really simple.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10

SELECT * FROM [TEST] ORDER BY [X]

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: I tend to agree with this one. It's very easy to prefix / suffix ANY string with the ROWCOUNT limitation/reset and it works for pretty much anything you put it around. That said, if the queries are going to be multi-statement you might have strange effects as ALL statements will get limited to n rows.

Comment: This is looking pretty good and seemed to work in the situation that led to the question.  But I have a funny feeling that there's some downside or gotcha that could catch me by surprise later.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest/simplest solution, it works for me, and nobody has mentioned any downsides.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can your function simply replace SELECT with SELECT TOP 10?

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TEST ORDER BY X
```

Comment: I think the issue is he knows the count AFTER he knows the subquery.

Comment: That would work in this case, but I'd like to be able to pass any query (as a string; updating my question to note this) to the function and get a query that yields the expected result.  Simply replacing the first SELECT doesn't yield the expected results for e.g. `select x from test1 union select x from test2` (you get all the rows).

Comment: It helps me to remember that the thing returned by a subquery is always a set (even if you SELECT TOP.. in the subquery) and sets have no order. If you have to use a subquery then JNK's approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can make proper use of CTE (Common Table Expressions) and Ranking Functions here.

```
; WITH CTE_RowNumbers AS 
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY X) AS ROWNUM FROM Users
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_RowNumbers WHERE ROWNUM < 10;
```

Simply replace the 10 with your variable.

This will provide exactly the same results in MS SQL as you would get from a ROWNUM function in Oracle.

Please note: The ROWNUM in this code snippet is just an alias, not a function in MSSQL and the real power sits in the use of the common table expressions and ranking functions used.

UPDATE: Masked CTE - replace the [VAR-Name] with your variables

```
 ; WITH CTE_RowNumbers AS 
    (
        SELECT [VAR-ColumnList], RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [VAR-OrderByList]) AS ROWNUM FROM [VAR-Table]
    )
    SELECT [VAR-ColumnList] FROM CTE_RowNumbers WHERE ROWNUM < [VAR-ResultSize];
```

Extract the input variables from your query as such:

SELECT [VAR-ColumnList] FROM [VAR-Table] ORDER BY [VAR-OrderByList]

You will also need to assign a value for [VAR-ResultSize], which by the looks of it is constant and get's set in your function?

Note: More flexibility is possible, if you need to add DESC or ASC to the order by, just extend your script and include that as a variable.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to programmatically convert the input query into this form?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I can try and point you in a direction... Look at your input query and the query I provided. Provided your input query always has the same basic structure (needs the ORDER BY) you can extract a number of variables (about 3). These will be the column list (* in this case), the table name, and the order by column list (X). Now you can create the basic structure of the CTE as a string and replace markers with the variables. I will update the answer and provide a mask for the CTE in a minute or so...

Comment: I want the function to assume as little about the structure of the input query as possible, so as to be as reusable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most logical solution would be to put your `ORDER BY` outside the subselect:

`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST) as sub ORDER BY X`

SQL Server expects the `TOP` and `ORDER` to be in the same scope.

Even if you `ORDER BY` on the inner query, if you did a `TOP` on the outside it wouldn't be guaranteed to be in the right order.

Comment: You need an alias on the derived table.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries are sets, and are therefore unordered, so you can't use them with `ORDER BY` unless you also use `TOP`.

If you want to limit the number of rows returned, and don't care which rows they are, you can just edit out any inner `ORDER BY`, if there was one, and then provide an alias for the subquery.

Original query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X
```

Edited and wrapped to return 10 rows:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST) AS EXPR
```

Or you can apply a TOP clause to the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TEST ORDER BY X) AS EXPR
```

Unfortunately, this is not guaranteed to return the same results as:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TEST ORDER BY X
```

For that, you would need to move the ORDER BY outside of the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST) AS EXPR ORDER BY X
```

You can also parameterize the number of rows to return:

```
SELECT TOP (@nrows) * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST) AS EXPR
```

With SQL Server 2012, you can almost achieve what you're really after, except in this case `ORDER BY` is required:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY X OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I wish I had SQL Server 2012.  This is still a good answer though, since I didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a temporary table:

```
select * into #temp from test order by x
select top 10 * from #temp where ...
```

Comment: Is that guaranteed to preserve the order?

Comment: Even though I've never seen it *not* preserve the order, I must honestly say that I don't really know whether there's a definition for how results are ordered selecting from a table without an index.

Comment: By the way: The same would be true if `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... ORDER BY ...)` worked, as you'd not be specifying an explicit order in your surrounding select.

Comment: That the order of the subquery wouldn't be passed on to the outer query is a very good point that a few people have made regarding this question.  In the Oracle case, I suppose it is because ROWNUM is some sort of implicit column.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you're looking for (I'm assuming SQL Server 2005 and above):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) rownum FROM test) tmp 
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Where 'x' is the column to order by and 'test' the table to select from. Also, a 'count' column is often also useful to return, especially if you do paging:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER() cnt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) rownum FROM test) tmp 
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: Is this equivalent to Charl Lamprecht's answer?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see his answer :( Its about the same, but mines single statement. Charl seems very engaged though and I'd credit him, great answer!

Answer (score -1):

Do one thing which is quite simple and straight forward:-->>

1. Remove the order by clause and
2. use the keyword 'AS' after the inner query.

Eg: SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST) AS X

Comment: I guess he also cares about the wanted result, not just have something that compiles

Comment: Removing the 'order by' clause would remove the ordering, which I want to preserve.  And aside from that, I don't believe removing an ORDER BY clause from a SQL string (and getting the correct result) without parsing the SQL is trivial (although I'd be pleased to be shown wrong on this).